# Where is the logic wrong in my code?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Kindly pardon my english.

I am taking an introductory course to C and I have some problems with the logic of my program. It will only sometimes produce the required output.

The task is to write a function that takes the elements of the array, return the largest even digit in the element.

`int ary1[] = {123, 456, -7890, 12};` Would return `-7890` as the largest value with `8` as the largest even digit and its occurrences.
`int ary2[5] = {-123, 654, 78, 15, 189};` Would return `189` as the largest value with `8` as the largest even digit and its occurrences.
`int ary3[2] = {9, 9};` Would not return anything.
`int ary4[] = {123, 123, 0, 12};` Would return `123` as the largest value with `2` as the largest even digit and its occurrences.
`int ary5[] = {24, 45, -789, 24, 1};` Would return `-789` as the largest value with `8` as the largest even digit and its occurrences.
`int ary6[] = {-749, -241, 1, 45};` Would return `45` as the largest value with `4` as the largest even digit and its occurrences.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void digitExtract(int[], int);

int main() {

    int ary1[] = { 123, 456, -7890, 12 };
    int ary2[5] = { -123, 654, 78, 15, 189 };
    int ary3[2] = { 9, 9 };
    int ary4[] = { 123, 123, 0, 12 };
    int ary5[] = { 24, 45, -789, 24, 1 };
    int ary6[] = { -749, -241, 1, 45 };
    int ary7[] = { 1, 3, 5 };

    printf("\nCalling function in ary1[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary1, 4);
    printf("\nCalling function in ary2[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary2, 5);
    printf("\nCalling function in ary3[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary3, 2);
    printf("\nCalling function in ary4[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary4, 4);
    printf("\nCalling function in ary5[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary5, 5);
    printf("\nCalling function in ary6[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary6, 4);
    printf("\nCalling function in ary7[]:\n");
    digitExtract(ary7, 3);
}

void digitExtract(int Array[], int array_size) {

    int tempValue;
    int x;
    int myArr[10] = { 0 };
    int evenCount = 0;

    int max = Array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if (Array[i] < 0) {
            Array[i] = -Array[i];
            if (Array[i] > max) {
                max = Array[i];
            }
        }

    }

    tempValue = (max < 0) ? -max : max;

    do {
        myArr[tempValue % 10]++;
        tempValue /= 10;
    } while (tempValue != 0);



    for (x = 8; x > 0; x -= 2) {
        if (myArr[x]>0) {
            printf("Displaying from inside of function():\n");
            printf("\nThe largest even digit: %d\n", x );
            printf("\nThe digit %d occurs %d times.\n", x, myArr[x]);

            evenCount++;
            break;
        }

    } if (evenCount == 0)
        printf("\nNo even digits found!\n\n");

}
```

I know there is an error in my logic as for `ary2[]` it will produce the even digit of `6` and it's occurrences when it should be `8`, but I don't know where.

The function will work for an array that has odd values as it's element.

Where or what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your task is to find the largest even digit, then find the largest value that has that digit... *not* find the largest value, then find the largest even digit within it.

I would start by writing a function named `max_even_digit` to operate on a single `int`, then verify that and work from there.

```
int max_even_digit(int x) {
    int max = 0;
    while (x) {
        int digit = x % 10;
        digit = digit < 0 ? -digit : digit;
        if (x % 2 == 0 && digit > max) {
            max = digit;
        }
        x /= 10;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Once you've done this, loop over your array as though you'd be finding the maximum value, but let the return value of `max_even_digit` take precedence over the actual value.

```
int max_even_digit_value(int *array, size_t size) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int max_value = array[0],
        max_digit = max_even_digit(max_value);
    while (--size) {
        int value = array[size],
            digit = max_even_digit(value);
        if (digit > max_digit || (digit == max_digit && value > max_value)) {
            max_value = value;
            max_digit = digit;
        }
    }

    return max_value;
}
```

Comment: I realized I did the reverse. I found the largest absolute value first, then found the largest even number for that value.

I was, as others have said, supposed to find the largest even number, and then associate that with the largest int in the array.

Comment: @Dumbfoundead Absolute value has no relevance here, as the last example you've given shows: `45` is returned rather than `-749`

Comment: should not `int max_even_digit(int x)` return `max` instead of `x`? `x` should be 0 after the loop.

Comment: @mch You have a very keen eye. Thanks :) I've made that correction.